# attribute multiple values to a single key ( dictionary) in Swift

Tags: swift

I'd like to ask how can I attribute several values to the same key then use those (same) key (from several values).
the exercise comes from https://www.weheartswift.com/dictionaries/
it's just an adaptation of his code.

i'm first creating a dictionary like this with multiple values for one keys:

```
      var code = [
    "X" : "a","b",
    "Y" : "c","d",
    "Z" : "e","f",

...
]
```

Then I'd like when I enter words containing a b c d e or f, it changes those letters to X Y or Z depending the dictionary

```
var encodedMessage = "abcdef"

var decoder: [String:[String]] = [:]

// reverse the code
for (key, value) in code {
    decoder[value] = key
}

//an error occurs here, what can i do to fix it?

var decodedMessage = ""

for char in encodedMessage {
    var character = "\(char)"

    if let encodedChar = decoder[character] {
        // letter
        decodedMessage += encodedChar
    } else {
        // space
        decodedMessage += character
    }
}
```

and since i prefer decoding the message without divide "letter" and "space" is there any better and easier way?
so it will be like, there won't be "space"

```
println(decodedMessage)
```

i'd like the decodedMessage is XXYYZZ

thank you already for those who can help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
let encodedMessage = "abcdef"

var code = ["X": ["a", "b"], "Y": ["c", "d"], "Z": ["e", "f"]]

var decoder: [String:String] = [:]

// reverse the code
for key in code.keys {
    for newCode in code[key]! {
        decoder[newCode] = key
    }
}


var decodedMessage = ""

for char in encodedMessage.characters {
    var character = "\(char)"

    if let encodedChar = decoder[character] {
        // letter
        decodedMessage += encodedChar
    } else {
        // space
        decodedMessage += character
    }
}
```

You just need to store them as an array.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but for: -- for code in code[key] --
I have an error: 'Array<String>?' does not have a member named 'Generator'. how to fix that? thanks